# Oracle - should I use exceptions or triggers?

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle11g, oracleexception

When trying to insert data into tables, it could fail for various reasons like unique key violated or foreign key violated.

I could use DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX exception to know unique key is violated but how do I know which key if there are multiple columns with unique marked? Should I use triggers in this case?

(I'm using exceptions to drive the flow of stored procedures instead of querying tables to make sure data being inserted is okay.)

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions (from constraints) or triggers? I say neither.

I would *strongly* recommend using application code and queries to drive the logic of your application, as opposed to triggers and constraints. Separating the logic from the error condition handling will only make the behaviour of your code appear more magical.

Although constraints are extremely useful as backup plan (in the case of application logic errors or changes), you are correct in that they do not assist with runtime error handling in the way that you want (i.e. do not help you expose the duplicate keys that the `INSERT` statement attempted to use).

As you have no doubt determined, you could very easily use a trigger to do what you describe, but ultimately all that means is that you're simply hiding the same logical test ("does this record already exist?") in a trigger as opposed to in the application code where your `INSERT` statement will exist. If multiple triggers exist on the table, you *may* also be going through the overhead of executing them needlessly, as if one will raise an error, any others which ran first would have been fruitless.

If you don't want to write additional statements to pre-check the condition of your data before running new `INSERT` statements, then I would suggest using something like this:

```
  INSERT INTO my_table (col1, col2)
  SELECT l_val1, l_val2
  FROM dual
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM my_table t
    WHERE t.col1 = l_val1
    AND t.col2 = l_val2
  )
```

At least then you will not violate the key, but you'll know if a row already existed by testing whether `SQL%ROWCOUNT` is 0 (no row inserted, so must already exist) or 1.

However, this still does not give you the key-violating values. You will have to write queries to find out which will violate the constraint.

Comment: you insert statement still does not tell about which column duplication attempted to occur in, right?

Comment: No, that's true. you're going to have to query it back.

Answer (score 0):

This is not what triggers are for. Remember that you [can not query the target table inside a trigger](https://www.google.com/search?q=oracle%20mutating%20table%20trigger&oq=oracle%20mutating%20table%20trigger), so you can not really check for uniqueness violations. I would say the best reason for a trigger is to make sure that rows are populated with default data, like an id from a sequence. Triggers also obfuscate code because it's not clear why the row that got inserted is different from your statement.

Constraints perform a useful function other than the obvious: the optimizer can use information in the constraints to judge an execution plan. A more efficient route can be calculated if the optimizer knows if a column is NOT NULL, for example.

The `INSERT` statement given by @Ben above is a good one, you can also wrap your statements inside an anonymous block:

```
BEGIN
    ... application code ... 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2) VALUES (val1, val2);
    EXCEPTION WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
        ... error handling code ...
    END;
    ... application continues...
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out triggers are out of the question. However, I need to know this: if I use your code above, how would I know which unique column the exception occurred on?

Comment: I don't think there is any way to tell that automatically. You'll probably have to do a `SELECT` to look for existing matching keys. I would say in most cases it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I suggest that you do **not** rely solely on application code to enforce uniqueness.  One key (pun intended) reason is that it is difficult to write code that does this correctly, particularly for cases where data is inserted or updated concurrently in multiple transactions.  It is comparatively simple to declare a unique constraint that the database will enforce correctly and efficiently.

If you want to know which *columns* have violated a unique constraint, one approach (and I realize it's not "pretty") is to:

1. Parse the constraint name from the error message (for example, as returned by `SQLERRM`).
2. Use some mechanism (like the data dictionary or a table of your own) to "look up" which columns correspond to the constraint.

If you want to know which *rows* have violated a unique constraint, you can use the `LOG ERRORS INTO` clause of the `INSERT` statement to log the offending rows into an error logging table, as outlined in [this example](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm#BCEGDJDJ).

If you want to know which rows *and* columns have violated a unique constraint, you can combine both methods -- you log the rows using the `LOG ERRORS INTO` clause, and then you parse the constaint name from the error message (which is also logged in the error logging table) and look up the corresponding columns.

Having said that, you don't necessarily need to choose between: a) checking the data first and only inserting it if it passes the checks, and, b) trying to insert the data and then reporting and/or acting on any errors.